# How do I setup "--" as a Sublime Text snippet tab trigger?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am currently working with fortran in Sublime Text and I'm adding some snippets to make the workflow faster.

Since fortran does not support the ++ or -- operators, I would like to make snippets that will change these operators to the explicit increment and decrement statements.

For example

```
a++
```

becomes

```
a = a + 1
```

and

```
a--
```

becomes

```
a = a - 1
```

I have successfully implemented the ++ snippet as follows.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[ = $TM_CURRENT_WORD + 1]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>++</tabTrigger>
    <description>i = i + 1</description>
    <scope>source.fortran</scope>
</snippet>
```

However, my implementation of the -- snippet fails to trigger.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[ = $TM_CURRENT_WORD - 1]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>--</tabTrigger>
    <description>i = i - 1</description>
    <scope>source.fortran</scope>
</snippet>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the -- snippet to trigger? Thanks.

Comment: Your `--` snippet triggers fine for me (ST2).

Comment: Does the `--` snippet trigger for you when it is appended to other text?  For example `--` will trigger for me, but `a--` will not trigger.

Comment: Odd, if I put a 'word separator' like `#` after a word/letter *that* will trigger.  Ex:  `a#--` when triggered becomes `a# = # - 1`.  But, otherwise, I was wrong in my comment, it is not working properly.  The `++` snippet works, though.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a key binding for the 3-key sequence of `minus,minus,tab` will do the trick:

```
{ "keys": ["-", "-", "tab"], 
  "command": "insert_snippet", 
  "args": {"name":"Packages/Fortran/MinusMinus.sublime-snippet"}
}
```